# How to share data in facebook

Tags: android

How to share data in Facebook through android application. is that any Intent call used to share our data in Facebook. I searched in google but i dint get any proper guidance. if anyone did this issue pls guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for share data on facebook you need to use facebook API

for facebook API follow this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) n go step by step